# Array of c-strings and pass by pointer method does not work

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference, c-strings

Assigning new values to an array of C strings using pass by pointer method does not work properly.

Inside the "LettersToCapital" method, new values are assigned to the C-string array properly, however, once the C-strings array contents are read outside the method the results are all wrong. All the function is supposed to do is to capitalize all the lowercase letters. I am definitely doing something wrong, but what could it be?

If on line 53 variable tempStr is replaced with a constant string literal e.g. "aqua" then the values remain the same outside the function. But assigning directly from a char array (tempStr) to char array pointer (*(string +i)) does not yield correct results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void LettersToCapital(char **string, int size);
void ReadOutAOC(char **string, int size);

int main()
{
    char *canadianProvinces[] = {"British Columbia", "Alberta", "Saskatchewan", "Manitoba", "Ontario", "Quebec", "New Brunswick", "Nova Scotia", "Prince Edward Island", "Newfoundland", "Yukon", "Northwest Territories", "Nunavut"};

    int numOfCanProv = sizeof(canadianProvinces) / sizeof(int);

    printf("\nNumber of Canadian provinces %d\n", numOfCanProv);

    // printing all provinces before conversion
    printf("\nBefore \"all to capital conversion\"\n\n");
    ReadOutAOC(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);    

    LettersToCapital(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);
    // Temp(canadianProvinces);

    // printing all provinces after conversion
    printf("\nAfter \"all to capital conversion\"\n");
    ReadOutAOC(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);
}

void ReadOutAOC(char **string, int size)
{
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("String outside the assignment method[%d]: %s\n", i + 1, *(string + i));
}

void LettersToCapital(char **string, int size)
{
    char tempStr[256];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(*(string + i)); j++)
        {
            if(*(*(string + i) + j) > 96 && *(*(string + i) + j) < 123)
                tempStr[j] = *(*(string + i) + j) - 32;
            else
                tempStr[j] = *(*(string + i) + j);
        }
        tempStr[strlen(*(string + i))] = '\0';
        *(string + i) = tempStr; // does not work
        //*(string + i) = "aqua"; // try this instead
        printf("String inside the assignment method[%d]: %s\n", i + 1, *(string + i));
    }
}
```

Expected output should be:

Before "all to capital conversion"

British Columbia

Alberta

Saskatchewan

...

After "all to capital conversion"

BRITISH COLUMBIA

ALBERTA

SASKATCHEWAN

...

Comment: `sizeof(canadianProvinces) / sizeof(int)` Looks suspect.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons suspect you say... I would say "all wrong" :-)

Comment: `*(string + i) = tempStr;` Here you are assigning your pointer to point to an object with automatic storage duration.  Once you leave the function, that data is garbage.  Also you are overwriting that data in the loop before you ever leave the function.

Comment: For *any* pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. Now think about that in the context of all your pointer arithmetic, which can be made so much simpler (and also less to write).

Comment: And don't use magic numbers like `32` or `123`. If you want to check if a character is upper case or not use [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper). And to do the conversion use [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) (which you can call even if the character already is upper case).

Comment: regarding: `char *canadianProvinces[] = { ... };`   This generates an array of character pointers to strings that are in readonly memory.  Such strings cannot be modified.  Trying to modify such strings should result in a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `int numOfCanProv = sizeof(canadianProvinces) / sizeof(int);`  Since the array is an array of `char *` this statement is very unreliable.   Also, the operator: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`, so a correct statement would be: `size_t numOfCanProv = sizeof(canadianProvinces) / sizeof(canadianProvinces[0]);`   Of course, anything that references the variable: `numOfCanProv` should handle `size_t` not `int`

Comment: Instead of ' *(string + i) = tempStr;' use 'strcpy(*(string + i) ,tempStr);'

Comment: Hmm, I knew my code was bad but I did not expect it to be this bad. This rather unpleasant revelation of how much  I don't know how to properly code even the simplest of programs has not only opened my eyes and forced me to confront the reality but has also strengthened my desire to learn more. Long story short, I came from C++ programming background (2+ years) looking into C language hopping that I would get some better insight and understanding of C++ background, principles and semantics of programming in general, only to find out that I never learned pointers properly and other basic rules.

Comment: By the way, thank you all for the insightful pinpointing of my programs faults and errors. I have learned a lot from you. Hopefully next time I won't appear on this site with such an embarrassing code trying to achieve seemingly simple results with illogical programming practice and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. note the proper method of accessing the data strings
4. note the appropriate usage of the header file: `ctype.h` and function: `toupper()`
5. unused variables, like `char tempStr[256];` and all references to that variable are eliminated
6. will result in a 'seg fault' event due to trying to modify data in readonly memory

And now the faulty code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void LettersToCapital(char **string, size_t size);
void ReadOutAOC(char **string, size_t size);

int main( void )
{
    char *canadianProvinces[] = 
    {
        "British Columbia", 
        "Alberta", 
        "Saskatchewan", 
        "Manitoba", 
        "Ontario", 
        "Quebec", 
        "New Brunswick", 
        "Nova Scotia", 
        "Prince Edward Island", 
        "Newfoundland", 
        "Yukon", 
        "Northwest Territories", 
        "Nunavut"
    };

    size_t numOfCanProv = sizeof(canadianProvinces) / sizeof(canadianProvinces[0]);

    printf("\nNumber of Canadian provinces %lu\n", numOfCanProv);

    // printing all provinces before conversion
    printf("\nBefore \"all to capital conversion\"\n\n");
    ReadOutAOC(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);    

    LettersToCapital(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);
    // Temp(canadianProvinces);

    // printing all provinces after conversion
    printf("\nAfter \"all to capital conversion\"\n");
    ReadOutAOC(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);
}

void ReadOutAOC(char **string, size_t size)
{
    printf("\n");

    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("String outside the assignment method[%lu]: %s\n", i + 1, string[i] );
}

void LettersToCapital(char **string, size_t size)
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        size_t j;
        for( j = 0; j < strlen( string[i] ); j++)
        {
            string[i][j] = (char)toupper( string[i][j] );
        }

        printf("String inside the assignment method[%lu]: %s\n", i + 1, string[i] );
    }
}
```

Running the above code results in the following output:

```
Before "all to capital conversion"


String outside the assignment method[1]: British Columbia
String outside the assignment method[2]: Alberta
String outside the assignment method[3]: Saskatchewan
String outside the assignment method[4]: Manitoba
String outside the assignment method[5]: Ontario
String outside the assignment method[6]: Quebec
String outside the assignment method[7]: New Brunswick
String outside the assignment method[8]: Nova Scotia
String outside the assignment method[9]: Prince Edward Island
String outside the assignment method[10]: Newfoundland
String outside the assignment method[11]: Yukon
String outside the assignment method[12]: Northwest Territories
String outside the assignment method[13]: Nunavut
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

using gdb to step through the program shows the cause of the seg fault event is this line:

```
string[i][j] = (char)toupper( string[i][j] );
```

because it is trying to change a value/byte/char in readonly memory

Suggest modifying the definition of the data to:

```
#define MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN 50
char canadianProvinces[][ MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN ] = 
    {
        "British Columbia", 
        "Alberta", 
        "Saskatchewan", 
        "Manitoba", 
        "Ontario", 
        "Quebec", 
        "New Brunswick", 
        "Nova Scotia", 
        "Prince Edward Island", 
        "Newfoundland", 
        "Yukon", 
        "Northwest Territories", 
        "Nunavut"
    };
```

Then adjusting the rest of the code to match would correct the problem.

The corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN 50

void LettersToCapital(char string[][ MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN ], size_t size);
void ReadOutAOC(char string[][ MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN ], size_t size);

int main( void )
{
    char canadianProvinces[][ MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN ] = 
    {
        "British Columbia", 
        "Alberta", 
        "Saskatchewan", 
        "Manitoba", 
        "Ontario", 
        "Quebec", 
        "New Brunswick", 
        "Nova Scotia", 
        "Prince Edward Island", 
        "Newfoundland", 
        "Yukon", 
        "Northwest Territories", 
        "Nunavut"
    };

    size_t numOfCanProv = sizeof(canadianProvinces) / sizeof(canadianProvinces[0]);

    printf("\nNumber of Canadian provinces %lu\n", numOfCanProv);

    // printing all provinces before conversion
    printf("\nBefore \"all to capital conversion\"\n\n");
    ReadOutAOC(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);    

    LettersToCapital(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);
    // Temp(canadianProvinces);

    // printing all provinces after conversion
    printf("\nAfter \"all to capital conversion\"\n");
    ReadOutAOC(canadianProvinces, numOfCanProv);
}

void ReadOutAOC(char string[][ MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN ], size_t size)
{
    printf("\n");

    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("String outside the assignment method[%lu]: %s\n", i + 1, string[i] );
}

void LettersToCapital(char string[][ MAX_PROV_NAME_LEN ], size_t size)
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        size_t j;
        for( j = 0; j < strlen( string[i] ); j++)
        {
            string[i][j] = (char)toupper( string[i][j] );
        }

        printf("String inside the assignment method[%lu]: %s\n", i + 1, string[i] );
    }
}
```

a run of the corrected code results in the following output:

```
Number of Canadian provinces 13

Before "all to capital conversion"


String outside the assignment method[1]: British Columbia
String outside the assignment method[2]: Alberta
String outside the assignment method[3]: Saskatchewan
String outside the assignment method[4]: Manitoba
String outside the assignment method[5]: Ontario
String outside the assignment method[6]: Quebec
String outside the assignment method[7]: New Brunswick
String outside the assignment method[8]: Nova Scotia
String outside the assignment method[9]: Prince Edward Island
String outside the assignment method[10]: Newfoundland
String outside the assignment method[11]: Yukon
String outside the assignment method[12]: Northwest Territories
String outside the assignment method[13]: Nunavut
String inside the assignment method[1]: BRITISH COLUMBIA
String inside the assignment method[2]: ALBERTA
String inside the assignment method[3]: SASKATCHEWAN
String inside the assignment method[4]: MANITOBA
String inside the assignment method[5]: ONTARIO
String inside the assignment method[6]: QUEBEC
String inside the assignment method[7]: NEW BRUNSWICK
String inside the assignment method[8]: NOVA SCOTIA
String inside the assignment method[9]: PRINCE EDWARD ISLAND
String inside the assignment method[10]: NEWFOUNDLAND
String inside the assignment method[11]: YUKON
String inside the assignment method[12]: NORTHWEST TERRITORIES
String inside the assignment method[13]: NUNAVUT

After "all to capital conversion"

String outside the assignment method[1]: BRITISH COLUMBIA
String outside the assignment method[2]: ALBERTA
String outside the assignment method[3]: SASKATCHEWAN
String outside the assignment method[4]: MANITOBA
String outside the assignment method[5]: ONTARIO
String outside the assignment method[6]: QUEBEC
String outside the assignment method[7]: NEW BRUNSWICK
String outside the assignment method[8]: NOVA SCOTIA
String outside the assignment method[9]: PRINCE EDWARD ISLAND
String outside the assignment method[10]: NEWFOUNDLAND
String outside the assignment method[11]: YUKON
String outside the assignment method[12]: NORTHWEST TERRITORIES
String outside the assignment method[13]: NUNAVUT
```

Comment: Thank you man, you've been really kind and helpful to me, drinks are on me if we ever meat each other. However, I'm disappointed to find out or to be more honest "be reminded again" that `char *string[]` is an array of pointers to characters that are in read-only memory.

Comment: If this answers your problem, then please select the answer